# CMOS Switch for -5, 10, and 5V

Tags: switches

Is there any way to make a switch that uses a 5V input to open a -5V or 10V connection? (so i can switch between making a line -5 and 10V).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a 5V relay with changeover contacts (SPCO) if you need to pass a lot of current.

Comment: He doesn't seem to know how much current he wants to pass, and seems to want to use individual NMOS and PNOS transistors.

Comment: @Leon, you are very knowledgeable, but as our highest rep user, can you please try to be a bit more civil and inviting? I understand frustration with basic questions, but it would be better to phrase it so the user does not feel like they are being attacked or mocked.

Comment: The question should be closed. He doesn't seem to know what he wants!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some switches like ADG733 have a separate Vss pin which can be at a lower potential than the logic GND; this means you could have a -10V supply on the Vss pin which would allow the gate to control up to a -10V signal whilst still having a 0-Vdd logic input. Unfortunately the ADG733 is limited to a 5.5V supply; but there are probably other parts that will do the same job (numbers escape me at the moment.)

Comment: +1 for Analog Devices.  They have the widest selection of odd-voltage analog switch parts.

Comment: I want to do this on-chip, not using outside switches.

Comment: @Cenoc If so you probably want some kind of CMOS transmission gate.

Comment: There would be a problem with the biasing of the substrate diode if I do that, wouldnt there be?

Comment: @Cenoc only if current flows from anode to cathode. You are talking to a CMOS idiot!

Comment: The substrate is tied to Vss, which is always the most negative voltage to prevent forward-biasing the substrate/nfet junction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking for an analogue switch that can handle signals in the range -5V to +10V or a digital interface to convert a 0 to 5V level into a -5v to +10V level. If it is the latter, my answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12972/level-shift-amplify/12998#12998) might help. This arrangement would work with N & P channel FETs with little modification.

Comment: I think he wants to connect something to either -5V or +10V, using 5V or 0V.